# Custom Input Mask with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, mask

I have a situation where I need to put a mask on an input field with the following pattern ' AAA999.AA999.AA.99 ' in this way : alphanumeric.alphanumeric.letters.numbers .
I've tried ui.mask but I want no placeholder and this plugin can't deal with it.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: ui,mask is on github edit it to meet your needs

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the input pattern attribute from html5? Then enforce its validation as follows ...

```
<form name='myform' novalidate='novalidate' ng-submit='subfunc()'>
    <input pattern='0-9'>
    <input type='submit' ng-disabled='myform.$invalid'>
</form>
```

Obviusly the regex pattern is wrong here and my syntax maybe minorly off but u get the idea.